# VB.NET Display file icons from Network Paths with calling Shell

Tags: vb.net, shell, listview, imagelist

I have this program that shows files with its icons using a `ListView` and it works a little bit fine but there's a problem, **some files**(.exe, .docx etc...)  don't show their right icon like this. how do I fix that?

[image]

This is how I call the Shell:

```
' declare the Win32 API function SHGetFileInfo'
Public Declare Auto Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal pszPath As String, ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As IntPtr
' declare some constants that SHGetFileInfo requires'
Public Const SHGFI_ICON As Integer = &H100
Public Const SHGFI_SMALLICON As Integer = &H1
' define the SHFILEINFO structure'
Structure SHFILEINFO
    Public hIcon As IntPtr
    Public iIcon As Integer
    Public dwAttributes As Integer
    <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
    Public szDisplayName As String
    <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=80)> _
    Public szTypeName As String
End Structure
Function RetrieveShellIcon(ByVal argPath As String) As Image
    Dim mShellFileInfo As SHFILEINFO
    Dim mSmallImage As IntPtr
    Dim mIcon As System.Drawing.Icon
    Dim mCompositeImage As Image
    mShellFileInfo = New SHFILEINFO
    mShellFileInfo.szDisplayName = New String(Chr(0), 260)
    mShellFileInfo.szTypeName = New String(Chr(0), 80)
    mSmallImage = SHGetFileInfo(argPath, 0, mShellFileInfo, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(mShellFileInfo), SHGFI_ICON Or SHGFI_SMALLICON)
    ' create the icon from the icon handle'
    Try
        mIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(mShellFileInfo.hIcon)
        mCompositeImage = mIcon.ToBitmap
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' create a blank black bitmap to return'
        mCompositeImage = New Bitmap(16, 16)
    End Try
    ' return the composited image'
    Return mCompositeImage
End Function
Function GetIcon(ByVal argFilePath As String) As Image
    Dim mFileExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(argFilePath)
    ' add the image if it doesn't exist'
    If cIcons.ContainsKey(mFileExtension) = False Then
        cIcons.Add(mFileExtension, RetrieveShellIcon(argFilePath))
    End If
    ' return the image'
    Return cIcons(mFileExtension)
End Function
```

and this is how I show file icons in my `ListView.

```
Sub lv1items()
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(Form2.TextBox1.Text)
    Dim exts As New List(Of String)
    ImageList1.Images.Clear()
    If di.Exists = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Source path is not found", "Directory Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        For Each fi As FileInfo In di.EnumerateFiles("*.*")

            lvi = New ListViewItem
            lvi.Text = fi.Name

            lvi.SubItems.Add(((fi.Length / 1024)).ToString("0.00"))
            lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToShortDateString)

            If exts.Contains(fi.Extension) = False Then
                Dim mShellIconManager As New Form1
                For Each mFilePath As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Form2.TextBox1.Text)
                    ImageList1.Images.Add(fi.Extension, GetIcon(mFilePath))
                    exts.Add(fi.Extension)
                Next
            End If
            lvi.ImageKey = fi.Extension
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ExtractAssociatedIcon takes a filepath as argument... If found it returns an icon. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: I did this one `Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)` but it throws an error `Value of '\\xxxx\users\user\downloads\desktop.ini' is not valid for 'filePath'.`

Comment: What I meant was it takes a string as in the executable path...

Comment: ohh, uhm what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a weird limitation of the .net implication

its really just making a call to shell32.dll

You should call the function in shell32 directly

something like this should work

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll")> 
Private Shared Function ExtractAssociatedIcon(hInst As IntPtr, lpIconPath As StringBuilder, ByRef lpiIcon As UShort) As IntPtr
End Function
```

_

```
Dim handle As IntPtr = SafeNativeMethods.ExtractAssociatedIcon(New HandleRef(Nothing, IntPtr.Zero), iconPath, index)
If handle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
    Return Icon.FromHandle(handle)
End If
```

The syntax might not be exactly correct, also there is a good blog post about how to pull that information from the registry (which won't always give you the correct answer, but its faster)

[Building a Better ExtractIcon](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/164) (he uses the SHGetFileInfo API in shell32.dll if that blog ever dies it will give people a place to start looking)

Comment: After looking at your code one more time, it looks like you are using the API directly, check out the link to building a better extract icon I think that will help you out

Comment: uhm yes I imported the shell32.dll sorry for not including in the post. I already worked on that blog but I failed, so many undeclared variables and I don't know how to fix it, sorry because I'm just new on this one. :(

Comment: can you help with his code? I converted his code but it seems like there's too many undeclared variables, I've been working with his code for hours, but I can't find out.

Comment: Yeah ill convert it for you